# Powershell Split String with "-" and number

Tags: powershell

```
$string = abc_test.txt-1234.xml
```

trying to split it "-" and any number,
so that 
first part after split would be abc_test.txt

I tried below.

```
$new = $string -Split'(?=\d)'  
$new[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the dash to your `-split`:

```
$new = $string -Split'(?=-\d)'
```